# Reverse column transform

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

In a machine learning model y_train is a string so column transform was applied in y_train before training the model ,How to remove the transform while printing the end result

Comment: If `y_train` is your target, why are you using a `ColumnTransformer`?  Please supply a minimal example.

Comment: I have to remove the transform in y_test  i applied transform in y_train as ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder',OneHotEncoder(),
                                        [1])],
                         remainder='passthrough')
y_train=ct.fit_transform(y_train)

Answer (score 1):

All scikit-learn transformers have `.inverse_transform` method to do so. e.g. `LabelEncoder` https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

```
>>> le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
>>> le.fit(["paris", "paris", "tokyo", "amsterdam"])
LabelEncoder()
>>> list(le.classes_)
['amsterdam', 'paris', 'tokyo']
>>> le.transform(["tokyo", "tokyo", "paris"])
array([2, 2, 1]...)
>>> list(le.inverse_transform([2, 2, 1]))
['tokyo', 'tokyo', 'paris']
```